# Java SimpleDateFormat returning wrong value in Date object

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a string to get a Date object, but it's always returning Sun. December 30, 2012 for the date. Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

I was using the same code using strings in YYYY-MM-dd format and it worked just fine, so I'm not sure why switching to this format is causing issues.

```
 public static Date getDateObjFromStr(String dateStr)
{
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
    Date dateObj;
    try {
        dateObj = formatter.parse(dateStr);
        return dateObj;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image: The string representing the date]

[image: The Date object returned by the SimpleDateFormat object]

Comment: Instead of returning null, can you print the stack trace when the Exception occurs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Case-sensitive

Uppercase `Y` represents [week-based year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26431882/642706).

Try using lowercase `y` instead

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```